# Sharepoint 2010 - multiple ip addresses

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, extranet, intranet, networking

I have Sharepoint 2010 installed in local network. SPS has local address **http://sps2010**, and has a public IP (e.g. **http://1.2.3.4**).

When I access SP via a public IP there are some links like ("Create Document", "Departments" etc) contain *local* server name. I would then get an error when browsing.

How can I setup multiple hostnames(IP's) for Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with Configure an Alternate Access Mapping in SharePoint 2010.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff679917.aspx

Comment: as I understand, intranet portal and internet portal should be in different webapplications, with different port numbers?

Comment: yes, the web application IIS port number are different.